# How do I uninstall Studio 3T on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I installed Studio 3T on Ubuntu 18.04 using the shell script provided by the vendor. Now, I want to uninstall it and have no idea how to. It does not show up as installed applications in Ubuntu's own package manager.
What do I do?

Comment: Have you check with vendor if install script can act as uninstall script? Or if vendor provide uninstall script/procedure?

Comment: I could not find anything on their Web page. Will try to contact them as well.

Comment: Have you check if its installed in `/opt`?

Answer (score 13):

To uninstall Studio 3T open terminal in its installation directory (/opt/studio3t) and type these commands:

```
sudo chmod +x uninstall
sudo ./uninstall
```

Uninstaller will appear in separate GUI window.

I think the more recent versions of Studio 3T will not require to uninstall previous versions manually.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is simple. 
Run the uninstall script from the folder in which the application is installed.

Typically, Studio 3T installs in the /home/studio3t folder by default. If not present at this path,
If there is a shortcut to launch "Studio 3T" on your desktop, just right-click on it and select "Properties". You should see the installation path mentioned in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the installation directory, named like `studio3t`, and you can find the uninstall script file `studio3t/uninstall`.

Open a terminal in that folder and run `./uninstall` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It will open the uninstall window. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue and it will uninstall and redirect to MongoDB website from where you installed the software.

It worked for me.